# Filter a list accordig to am other list, when a join is not applicable

Tags: apache-pig

Suppose that one has a list of `Intervals` and a list of `Points` which comes from two different query plans.

Suppose that the signature of the `Intervals` list is:

```
Intervals : { (start:int, stop:int) }
```

therefore, it is a list of couples.

Converesly, `Points` is a list of singletons:

```
Points: { (coordinate:int) }
```

What I want to do, is retrieving from the `Points` set all the points which are included in at least one interval of the `Intervals` set.

What I did, it to implement this trivial plan:

```
cp = CROSS Points, Intervals;
cp_filtered = FILTER cp BY start < coordinate and coordinate < stop;
filtered_point = FOREACH cp_filtered GENERATE coordinate;
```

Of course, if the cardinality of the lists is high, the cross product is not a good choice.

I was wondering how problems like this are usually solved in PigLatin. Could you help me?

Comment: What version of pig are you using?

Comment: I checked out from svn a couple of weeks ago. I'm still exploiring Pig, therefore if a version has some particular interesting features I can easly change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [Python UDF](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/udf.html#python-udfs) that converts the interval into a range, then `JOIN` with the range:

#### myudf.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

@outputSchema('expanded: {(num:int)}')
def expand(start, end):
    return [ (x) for x in range(start + 1, end) ]
```

#### myscript.pig

```
REGISTER 'myudf.py' using jython as myudf ;   

-- expand creates a bag of all numbers in the range 
B = FOREACH Intervals GENERATE FLATTEN(myudf.expand(start, end)) ;

-- Maybe do DISTINCT on B to speed up the JOIN?

C = JOIN B by num, Points by coordinate ;
```

I'm not sure if this is your fastest option, but it should be much faster than a `CROSS` for larger data sets.